# pass to the server an complex payload of both "text/csv" and "application/json"

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, http, https

I am trying to pass to the server a complex payload that looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "",
    "files": [
        {
            "file_name": "test_CSV.csv",
            "file_type": "text/csv",
            "table_name": "test_CSV",
            "file_size": 1801440,
            "binary": ArrayBuffer <- this is a CSV
        }
    ]
}
```

What would be the most appropriate way to do it?
If I try to do with `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, the ArrayBuffer gets lost. If I try to do it with "text/csv" I cannot recover the remaining information about the file. What is the 'best-practices' in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JSON data format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) doesn't support the ArrayBuffer data type. It **only** supports objects, arrays, strings, numbers, true, false and null.

If you want to embed CSV into JSON then it needs to be a string. CSV files are text files so will happily fit into strings.

(If you wanted to include binary data in JSON then you'd need to encode it as a string, e.g. using base64, but there's no need for that with CSV).

Comment: thank you, Quentin. is this the same way to handle excel files?

Comment: Excel files are not text so see the last paragraph of the answer.